# Python - Gathering File Information Recursively Leads to Memory Error

Tags: python, recursion

I am writing a script to recurse over all directories and subdirectories of a starting folder but I'm running into memory errors (the error is `MemoryError`). My guess would be that maybe my `data_dicts` list is getting too big but I'm not sure. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import os

# example data dictionary
data_dict = {
    'filename': 'data.csv',
    'folder':   'R:/',
    'size':     300000
}

def get_file_sizes_folder(data_dicts, starting_folder):
# Given a list of file information dictionaries and a folder, iterate over the files
# in the folder to get their information and append it to the list. 
# Also recurse through subdirectories
    for entry in os.scandir(starting_folder):
        if not entry.name.startswith('.'):
            if entry.is_file():
                size = entry.stat().st_size
                filename = entry.name
                folder = os.path.dirname(entry.path)
                temp_dict = {'filename': filename, 'size': size, 'folder': folder}
                data_dicts.append(temp_dict.copy())
            else:
                print(entry.path)
                data_dicts.extend(get_file_sizes_folder(data_dicts, entry.path))

    return data_dicts

d = get_file_sizes_folder([], 'R:/')
```

Comment: why are you not using [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.walk)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't supply `data_dicts` as an argument to your function `get_file_sizes_folder()`. Doing so will produce many, many duplicates of your entries, at a rate that is probably nearly factorial. No wonder that your computer runs out of memory very quickly!

Instead, use only `starting_folder` as an argument, and simply create a new list `data_dicts` in the first line of your function, like so:

```py
def get_file_sizes_folder(starting_folder):
# Given a list of file information dictionaries and a folder, iterate over the files
# in the folder to get their information and append it to the list. 
# Also recurse through subdirectories
    data_dicts = []
    for entry in os.scandir(starting_folder):
        if not entry.name.startswith('.'):
            if entry.is_file():
                size = entry.stat().st_size
                filename = entry.name
                folder = os.path.dirname(entry.path)
                temp_dict = {'filename': filename, 'size': size, 'folder': folder}
                data_dicts.append(temp_dict)
            else:
                print(entry.path)
                data_dicts.extend(get_file_sizes_folder(entry.path))

    return data_dicts
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't perform a recursion at all. Use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.walk)

Example:

```
def get_file_sizes_folder(starting_folder):
    data_dicts = list()
    for root, _, files in os.walk(starting_folder):
        data_dicts.extend({
            'filename': f, 
            'size': os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, f)),
            'folder': root,
        } for f in files)

    return data_dicts

d = get_file_sizes_folder('R:/')
```

Comment: Thanks. I have some questions though. You list `_` as a parameter yet I don't see you using it. Also, I notice that you use some sort of list comprehension, yet you don't have enclosing brackets like so: `[{} for f in files]`. Could you please explain this?

Comment: The `_` is because I don't need the `folders` parameter of the command. It is a convention to use underscore for unwanted/unused parameters. The list comprehension is not a list comprehension, it is a generator expression. I encourage you to test it and check that the behaviour is the expected one.